# Converting/importing existing ROS code to rosjava

Tags: ros, teleoperation, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been reading through the rosjava documentation, but have yet to find a clear answer to my question. I have ROS working flawlessly on my Coroware Corobot, and want to be able to control it from the ROS Teleop application.

Is there a way I can import or convert the current ros code to rosjava? Or is there a better way to control the robot using the ROS Teleop without rosjava?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12104/converting/importing-existing-ros-code-to-rosjava/) by [dyourk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1446/dyourk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-11-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a lot of ways to teleop your robot. You'll have to choose the one that fits your needs best.

As for converting existing ROS nodes into Java, it's often possible but rosjava is still in alpha (i.e. the API is subject to change and does frequently) and is missing some features found in roscpp/rospy. See the [rosjava wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava) page and [javadoc](http://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava/doc/index.html).

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0